# 'redirect_uri_mismatch', error_description: 'AADB2C90006: for Web app hosted in App service behind Frontdoor

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c, azure-front-door

My web app is developed using Aspnet Razor pages which uses AD B2C for authentication. This works locally without any errors. I have followed the instructions to setup the RedirectUrl in B2c and configure the same url for CallbackPath (without the base url, as shown below) in the appsetting.json file.

```
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "#{ADB2C_Instance}#",
    "ClientId": "#{ADB2C_ClientId}#",
    "Domain": "#{ADB2C_Domain}#",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "#{ADB2C_SignUpSignInPolicyId}#",
    "TenantId": "#{ADB2C_TenantId}#",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "#{ADB2C_ClientSecret}#"
  }
```

In Azure, its setup this way -

Frontdoor => App Service

Custom domain is setup on the Frontdoor (https://abc.testwebsite.com) and
App Service default url (https://abc-testwebsite.azurewebsites.net)

In the ADB2c, app registration I have added the RedirectUrl using Frondoor custom url (https://abc.testwebsite.com/signin-oidc)

Nuget Microsoft.Identity.Web is doing all the magic for the login. It automatically redirects to the AD b2c sigin-oidc. This works correctly in the local pc. However, in Azure, as the "**CallbackPath**" is without the baseurl, its picking up the App service default base url and failing with the error - 'redirect_uri_mismatch'. I tried adding the App service Url in the AD b2c then it redirects to App service url ( https://abc-testwebsite.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc) instead of Frontdoor Url (https://abc.testwebsite.com/signin-oidc)

Is there a workaround available for this? or am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to solve this problem -

Azure App service uses XForwardedHeaders to determine the host name. I have added the below lines in the program.cs. That did the trick. It automatically picked the correct host name after this change and logged in correctly.

```
 services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
      options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    });

.....

//Forwarded headers middleware should run before other middleware
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```